# actual address is Different from the billing address on my ticket

Tags: tickets

So I recently bought a flight ticket and someone paid for it and added his address where it is says billing address but that’s not where l live. Would it be a problem for me since the address of the person who paid is showing on top of the ticket and of which that’s not my actual address as the passenger

Comment: You might want to check out the airline’s T&C regarding using a 3rd party’s credit card to be on the safe side, some airlines will ask to see said credit card before checking-in at the airport https://www.triptipedia.com/tip/dg6si2W/airlines-verifying-your-credit-card-at-check-in

Answer (score 3):

No. People have multiple addresses and sometimes companies pay for tickets for employees and the billing address will be different. The billing address is generally used for verification during the transaction which is why there is a separate set of fields for billing info. In some cases, you have a check-box or default when registering to make all addresses the same. You can usually fill in your contact details on the airline website and you may be asked during online check-in, if you have not done so by then.